# How to obtain signed in Azure B2C user’s id when submitting web form data to MySQL database table?

Tags: mysql, asp.net, webforms, azure-ad-b2c, userid

I currently have an ASP.NET web which sends the inputs of each request to MySQL database table. Since I’m using Azure B2C to register and login my users, how can I send the user’s id to the database table? Do I have to add a connection string to reference the Azure B2C database? I can’t find any information on this. If there is an alternate way of distinguishing who is submitting them form, I’m open to accept any ideas. I just need to know who is submitting each form to me.

Comment: Is your application getting a token from Azure AD B2C and needs to update the data in DB, and you want to find out how to identify the user? Can you add some clarity to the question to explain these aspects?

Comment: I suspect you want this for columns like 'created by', 'modified by', etc, correct?

Comment: @spottedmahn well I just want to know who is submitting each form which gets sent to the database. Otherwise I will have all of these submissions but I won’t know know who send which form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select the `User's Object ID` to be returned as a claim in the token.  You can then read that claim in ASP.Net and pass it along to MySQL.

[See line 34 of this sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnet-webapp-and-webapi/blob/master/TaskService/Controllers/TasksController.cs#LC34) app on how to read the `objectId`.

[image: application claims]

[image: select claims/attributes]

Comment: I have the user object selected under application claim but how do I read that claim from asp.net? And do I have to add any packages or references to my asp.net web form?

Comment: Thanks I will try this out when I get home. I also saw this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35750295/read-azure-ad-login-user-details-in-asp-net would this work too?

Comment: And then I would have to set another INSERT INTO statement in my web.config file to send the user’s object ID to my database table?